# BeautifulSoup returning `NoneType` on any soup command

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the WSJ using BeautifulSoup, but it seemingly can never find the element with id="top-news", which is always available on the home page. I've tried find(), find_all() and a variety of other methods and they all return a `NoneType` for any method called on my `results` object.

I'm trying to extract metadata about the top news articles, primarily the article title and url. Each article's metadata is under a class named "WSJTheme--headline--7VCzo7Ay ", but I only want those located under the "top-news" div.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from shutil import copyfile

URL = 'https://www.wsj.com'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='top-news')

topArticles = results.find_all('div', class_='WSJTheme--headline--7VCzo7Ay ')
```

Comment: What are you trying to extract from site and also in your `result` you should mention `tag-name` please update your post with this information

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I updated the post with more info about what I'm trying to extract. What do you mean by mentioning the tag name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `User-Agent` to get correct response from the server:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.wsj.com/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for headline in soup.select('#top-news span[class*="headline"]'):
    print(headline.text)
```

Prints:

```
Oil Giants Dealt Defeats as Climate Pressures Intensify
At Least Eight Killed in San Jose Shooting
HSBC to Exit Most U.S. Retail Banking
Amazon-MGM Deal Marks Win for Hedge Funds
Cities Reverse Defunding the Police Amid Rising Crime
Federal Prosecutors Have Asked Banks for Information About Archegos Meltdown
Why a Grand Plan to Vaccinate the World Against Covid Unraveled
Inside the Israel-Hamas Conflict and One of Its Deadliest Hours in Gaza
Eric Carle, ‘The Very Hungry Caterpillar’ Author, Dies at 91
Wynn May Face U.S. Action for Role in China’s Push to Expel Businessman
Walmart to Sell New Line of Gap-Branded Homegoods
```

Comment: where do you find that specific syntax for the .select() function? I don't see it anywhere in BS4's documentation and the actual class name for the headline text appears to be `WSJTheme--headlineText--He1ANr9C `, not just `headline`.

Comment: @Pigpocket `.select()` method accepts CSS selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp  `span[class*="headline"]` select all `<span>` tags which has attribute `class=` with string that contains `"headline"`